# Giving a video file a specific name before saving to photo roll - iOS

Tags: ios, video, photo

I am working on an iOS app and I recently implemented a imagePicker in a popover that allows a user to record photos and videos. I would like to store these in the iPad's photo roll so that the user can sync them in iTunes later. I've been able to do this successfully, but I would like to give each photo and video a unique name that contains useful information about the photo and video so I can load them later. Specifically, I would like to store the photo using a property of the class, live_trial_id, as the filename. Below is the code that I am currently using to store my photos and videos to the photo roll. I understand that I could do this with metadata for pictures, but for the videos I am lost. Thanks in advance for any help with this issue!

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
UIImage *originalImage, *editedImage, *imageToSave;

// Handle a still image capture
if( [mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){

    editedImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                               UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                                 UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    if (editedImage) {
        imageToSave = editedImage;
    } else {
        imageToSave = originalImage;
    }

    // Get the image metadata
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceType pickerType = picker.sourceType;
    if(pickerType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
    {
        NSDictionary *imageMetadata = [info objectForKey:
                                       UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];
        // Get the assets library
        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock imageWriteCompletionBlock =
        ^(NSURL *newURL, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog( @"Error writing image with metadata to Photo Library: %@", error );
            } else {
                NSLog( @"Wrote image with metadata to Photo Library");
            }
        };

        // Save the new image (original or edited) to the Camera Roll
        [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[imageToSave CGImage]
                                     metadata:imageMetadata
                              completionBlock:imageWriteCompletionBlock];
    }
}

if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"]) {
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceType pickerType = picker.sourceType;
    if(pickerType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
    {
        NSURL *mediaURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        // Get the assets library
        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        ALAssetsLibraryWriteVideoCompletionBlock videoWriteCompletionBlock =
        ^(NSURL *newURL, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog( @"Error writing image with metadata to Photo Library: %@", error );
            } else {
                NSLog( @"Wrote image with metadata to Photo Library");
            }
        };

        // Save the new image (original or edited) to the Camera Roll
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:mediaURL
                              completionBlock:videoWriteCompletionBlock];

    }
}
```

I would also like to avoid creating a custom library or custom metadata if at all possible. I really just wanted to change the filename on the way to the photo roll

Comment: Thanks your Code Helped me to Identify between a Video or an Image Being Captured ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up answering my own question. What I wanted to do was to save to the application's documents directory instead of the photo roll. This allowed me to access the files that I had saved and also to sync them to the computer when attached later.